# How to get a parent from a child FK?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model)
 name = models.CharField()

class User(models.Model)
 name = models.CharField()

class List(models.Model)
 user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Item(models.Model)
 name = models.CharField()
 list = models.ForeignKey(List)
 user = models.ForeignKey(User)
 product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
```

views.py

```
class ListView(View)
  def get(self, request, pk)
    list = List.objects.get(id=pk)
    return render(request, "list.html", {"list" : list})
```

list.html

```
{% for item in list.item_set.all %}
  {{ item.name }}
  {{ item.user.name }} - ??
  {{ item.product.name }} - ??
{% endfor %}
```

How get user.name и product.name?

**I tried it:**

1. `{% item.user_set.first.name %}` - does not work
2. `{% for user in item.user_set.all %}{{ user.name }}{% endfor %}` - does not work
3. Model method:

   ```
   def get_user(self): 
       self.user_ser.get() #does not work
   ```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Exactly that way: `{{ item.user.name }}`. What is not working with that?

Comment: Not work(
```
{{ item.user }} # get user id
```

Comment: yes, therefore it hould be `{{ item.user.username }}`. A `User` object has no name, but a `username`.

Comment: ` {{ item.user.name }} # returns an empty `

Comment: not `{{ item.user.name }}`, but `{{ item.user.username }}` (so `.username`, instead of `.name`)

Comment: According to the model definition it should actually be `{{ item.user.name }}`. If you get an empty string then it is probably empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since an `Item` has a `ForeignKey` to a `Product` object, you can access the related object with `item.product`, so you can render this with:

```
{{ item.product.name }}
{{ item.user.name }}
```

If you use the standard `User` module, it is `{{ item.user.username }}`. It is possible that this is empty, for example if the `name` of the related user is the empty string `''`.

In order to retrieve the elements more efficient however, it might be better to perform a [**`.prefetch_related(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to retrieve these items in *bulk*:

```
class ListView(View)
  def get(self, request, pk)
    list = List.objects.prefetch_related('item_set', 'item_set__product', 'item_set__user').get(id=pk)
    return render(request, "list.html", {'list' : list})
```

Answer (score 3):

From user : `{{user.items}} # to access to the items objects` 
From item: `{{item.user.name}} # to access to the user name field`

```
class Item(models.Model)
 name = models.CharField()
 list = models.ForeignKey(List)
 user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='items')
 product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
```

Answer (score 0):

It works!
My error was that I looked at the field names in the database, not in the file models.py. They are different.

Thank you for your help!

All the answers above are correct!